# Web-интерфейс для приложения в C#

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

приложение на c# управляет устройством через lpt порт, как сделать web-интерфейс для него ?

Comment: asp.net mvc??

Comment: Сделайте свое приложение библиотекой классов(в свойствах проекта), далее подключать данную библиотеку в свое Web-приложение, дальше просто в своем веб-приложении используете методы из вашей библиотеки для работы с портом.